# Should I use multiple Meteor.js apps or a single app?

Tags: performance, meteor, server, hosting, meteor-up

I have different applications running with Meteor JS. Each one starts its server under different ports when running locally. When hosted, I have them under sub-domains like messenger.mydomain.com, courses.mydomain.com, mydomain.com.  I'm now considering performance if running multiple apps like this would have more odd impact on the server or combining the files into one so that all the 3 apps will be like: mydomain.com/messenger, mydomain.com/courses, mydomain.com.

Based on these two scenarios which will have a far more negative impact on the server?

Comment: What do you consider as negative impact?

Comment: I mean server performance. I am of the opinion that running multiple Meteor apps will take more server resources like memory, CPU against running an app.

Comment: But that is just three more node processes running in parallel. Your CPU should handle that. In the end are the most important loads db r/w and your webserver request handling. I think they will not differ much on those two setups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too have hosted 4-5 such Meteor apps on a single server using PM2 process Manager. Initially when a Meteor app starts it utilizes around 80-90 MB of RAM. Further, the consumption of the RAM and other parameters will depend on how good is your server CPU, Cores, etc.

Generally is it not an issue hosting such servers. But the most important fact you should remember is the no. of concurrent users connecting your different Meteor instances at various point of time. Currently, I have 40 concurrent users hitting on 4 instances each.

You just need to maintain server check every in order to purge process logs, even you might restart the servers as needed during downtime.

Below is the example of my hosting on CENTOS7. Everythings goes smoothly if you consider above precautions.

[image]